# Pygame drawn ball not being animated

Tags: python, pygame

So I have drawn a ball using `pygame.draw.circle`, and I've tried animating it, but it didn't work
here's my code:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", (100,100), 5, 5)
fps = 60

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", (100,100), 5, 5)
    vel = 5
    ball.x += vel

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I was expecting the ball to move to the right.
I tried putting the vel variable above the loop, but still same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the ball at the position stored in the `ball` object (`pygame.Rect`) instead of the constant position (100, 100):

<s>`ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", (100,100), 5, 5)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", ball.center, 5, 5)
```

The background must also be cleaned in every frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
vel = 5
ball = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 10, 10)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    ball.x += vel    

    screen.fill("black")
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, "White", ball.center, 5, 5)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```